# How to print numbers divisble by two in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.6

I used a for loop to print the numbers between 0 and 100 that are multiples of three. Now I have to print the ones that are divisible by two and I cant seem to get it to work properly.

I need to show both and I did that below, but is there a way to incorporate the second for loop into the first one in order to print both without printing the divisible ones in the same loop as the multiples of three.

Code:

```
for x in range(0,100,3):
    print(x)
for  n in range(0,100,3):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        print(n)
```

Comment: Notice that the numbers which are divisible by both 2 and 3 are actually divisible by 6.

Comment: a own loop for 0-100 which can be devide by 2 which are multi of 3 AND div by 2?

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in range (0,100,3):
    print("Multi of 3: " + str(x))

    if(x % 2 == 0):
        print("Div by 2: " + str(x))

    if(x % 3 == 0 AND x % 2 == 0 ):
        print("Both: " + str(x))
```

Comment: @LenIBoy Hello. If there is a need to print a final statement, the number in question is neither divisible for 3 nor 2, which will be the best way to close the loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in range (0,100,2):
    print(x)
```

This will print the ones divisible by 2 excluding 100

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `if` statement to check for numbers which are divisible by `2`. If a number is evenly divisible by `2` then the number remainder will be `0`. To check this, you can use the `%` (modulo) operator.

So, you'd have:

```
for x in range (0, 100, 3):
    # check if x is evenly divisible by 2
    # i.e. is the remainder zero when divided by 2
    if x % 2 == 0:
      print(x)
```

Alternatively, you could go up in steps of `6`, since `6` is the [LCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of `2` and `3`.

```
for x in range(0, 100, 6):
    print(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

not a expert in python but logicaly all language has a modulo operator

```
sum = 0

for i in range (yourange):
  if (i % 3 == 0)
      sum += i
return sum
```